# How to find a parametric equation of uniform motion?

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions

requirement:

1.The trajectory of the parametric equation is a closed polygon.
2.Try not to use trigonometric functions and `Mod`.Only `Abs` is allowed.

For example, the three vertices of a triangle are:{0, 0}, {200, 0}, {0, 200}. I tried to solve the triangle trajectory parameter equation, but I failed.Here's the code:

```
f[t_] := a* Abs[b*t + c] - d*Abs[t + e] + ff*t + g
f2[t_] := a2*Abs[t + b2] - c2*Abs[d2*t + e2] + ff2*t + g2
sol = Solve[
  f[0] == 0 && f2[0] == 0 && f[600/(400 + 200 \[Sqrt]2)] == 200 && 
   f2[600/(400 + 200 \[Sqrt]2)] == 0 && 
   f[(3 (200 + 200 \[Sqrt]2))/(400 + 200 \[Sqrt]2)] == 0 && 
   f2[(3 (200 + 200 \[Sqrt]2))/(400 + 200 \[Sqrt]2)] == 200 && 
   f[3] == 0 && f2[3] == 0 && f[300/(400 + 200 \[Sqrt]2)] == 100 && 
   f2[300/(400 + 200 \[Sqrt]2)] == 0 && 
   f[(3 (200 + 100 \[Sqrt]2))/(400 + 200 \[Sqrt]2)] == 100 && 
   f2[(3 (200 + 100 \[Sqrt]2))/(400 + 200 \[Sqrt]2)] == 100 && 
   f[(3 (300 + 200 \[Sqrt]2))/(400 + 200 \[Sqrt]2)] == 0 && 
   f2[(3 (300 + 200 \[Sqrt]2))/(400 + 200 \[Sqrt]2)] == 100, {a, b, c,
    d, e, ff, g, a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, ff2, g2}, Reals](*0<=t<=3*)
```

I think there may be a mistake in the equations.A possible correct answer:

```
{100 (((Sqrt[2] + 1) Abs[Sqrt[2] - (Sqrt[2] + 2) t + 1])/(Sqrt[2] + 
       2) - (2 Sqrt[2] + 3) Abs[t + 1/Sqrt[2] - 1] + (Sqrt[2] + 2) t),
  100 ((3 Sqrt[2] + 4) Abs[
       t + 1/Sqrt[2] - 1] - (2 Sqrt[2] + 
        3) (Abs[Sqrt[2] - (Sqrt[2] + 2) t + 1] + 2 t - 2))/(Sqrt[2] + 
     2)}(*0<=t<=1*)
```

[image: verification]

Related [post](https://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/146505-Explicit-Equation-Of-Arbitrary-Continuous).

Comment: Is this a homework problem? Why the restriction on Trigonometric functions and `Mod`?

Comment: @CATrevillian It may increase the difficulty of the question.

Answer (score 1):

First define triangle as an interpolation function depending on the arclength

```
p = {{0, 0}, {200, 0}, {0, 200},{0,0}} ; (* points*)
sp = Join[{0}, Accumulate@Map[Norm, Rest[p] - Most[p]]]
ip = Interpolation[MapThread[{#2, #1 } &, {p, sp} ],InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

the parametric solution you are looking for is `ip[v t]`!

```
ParametricPlot[ip[(400 + 200 Sqrt[2]) t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

**addendum**

`Piecewise` gives a explicit solution

```
pcw[s_] := Piecewise[{
{p[[1]] (200 - s)/200 + p[[2]] s /200, 0 <= s < 200},
{p[[2]] (200 + 200 Sqrt[2] - s )/( 200 Sqrt[2]) +p[[3]] (s - 200   )/(200 Sqrt[2]) , 200 <= s < 200 + 200 Sqrt[2]}, 
{p[[3]] (400 + 200 Sqrt[2] - s )/200  +p[[4]] (s - (200 + 200 Sqrt[2]) )/200  , 200 + 200 Sqrt[2] <= s <= 400 + 200 Sqrt[2]} 
}]

pcw[(400 + 200 Sqrt[2]) t]
```

$\begin{cases}
 \left\{\left(400+200 \sqrt{2}\right) t,0\right\} & 0\leq \left(400+200 \sqrt{2}\right) t<200 \\
 \left\{\frac{-\left(\left(400+200 \sqrt{2}\right) t\right)+200
   \sqrt{2}+200}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{\left(400+200 \sqrt{2}\right) t-200}{\sqrt{2}}\right\} & 200\leq
   \left(400+200 \sqrt{2}\right) t<200+200 \sqrt{2} \\
 \left\{0,-\left(\left(400+200 \sqrt{2}\right) t\right)+200 \sqrt{2}+400\right\} & 200+200
   \sqrt{2}\leq \left(400+200 \sqrt{2}\right) t\leq 400+200 \sqrt{2}
\end{cases}$

Comment: Assume `v = (400 + 200 Sqrt[2])/3`. It seems to be an incomplete numerical solution. `Piecewise` function needs to be added. The problem can be found by drawing the image of the interpolation function with `ParametricPlot`. But it does move at a uniform speed.

Comment: @fcwyq See my modified answer!

Comment: A Good Interpolation method. But I prefer explicit analytic expressions: `{x[t],y[t]}`.

Comment: Change `Interpolation` to `Piecewise`: In both cases you have explicit parametric solutions!

Comment: Yes, but I need an analytic expression. For example: `x[t] = a*Cos[t]`, `y[t] = a*Sin[t]`.

Comment: This is indeed a method. What should we do without using `Piecewise`?

Comment: @fcwyq Now I offered you two solutions and you ask for a third??? Try `Which`.

Comment: In a sense `Which` is equal to `Piecewise`. I mean, try to use the undetermined coefficient method. You can refuse to answer the third question.

Answer (score 0):

The following code was originally written by @flc:

```
pts = Transpose[{{0, 0}, {200, 0}, {0, 200}, {0, 0}}];
c = Prepend[#/Last@# &@Accumulate@Abs@Differences@# &[{1, I} . pts], 
   0];
f = FullSimplify[
  RealAbs[t - c] . 
   LinearSolve[Abs@Outer[Subtract, #, #] &@c, Transpose@pts]]
ParametricPlot[f, {t, 0, 1}]
Plot[Evaluate@Norm@D[f, t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: speed]

We obtained the second different correct answer:

```
{100 ((2 + Sqrt[2]) RealAbs[
      t] - (3 + 2 Sqrt[2]) RealAbs[-1 + 1/Sqrt[2] + t] + 
    RealAbs[1 + Sqrt[2] - (2 + Sqrt[2]) t]/Sqrt[2]), 
 100 ((2 + Sqrt[2]) RealAbs[-1 + t] + (1 + Sqrt[2]) RealAbs[-1 + 1/
       Sqrt[2] + t] - 
    1/2 (2 + Sqrt[2]) RealAbs[1 + Sqrt[2] - (2 + Sqrt[2]) t])}
```

The 2 function images is congruent within the definition domain [0,1], but not identical outside the definition domain [0,1].
[image: compare]